# Protection Diodes on Bidirectional Bus With Two Voltages

Tags: circuit-protection

I am designing a circuit that will connect to an existing device (the SNES) and communicate via a bidirectional data bus. As the circuits run at different voltages (5V TTL and 3V CMOS) and have separate power sources, they could be powered independently of each other, which could cause problems. Additionally, the FPGA I am using needs to connect to the bus, but it is not 5V-tolerant. I was wondering if the common I/O protection diode schematic could be modified like so for a bidirectional bus.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkyCbd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is 1M a proposed value, or a typo by any chance? Diode clamping works in the high-to-low direction, but no amount of diodes or resistors can amplify low up to high. Have you considered a bus interface like SN74LXC8T245? Even a TXB0108 (or relatives) might do well here.

Comment: @TimWilliams 1M is a proposed value. I chose it because 3.3 is high enough to read as high for 5V TTL and because when doing some testing in the Falstad simulator with, when the 5V side is driving the bus, it draws a lot of current with a small resistor. The diodes on the 5V side are meant to protect it when it is off, but the 3.3V side is on, in addition to the code loaded onto the FPGA. I hadn't considered a bus interface like the ones you mentioned, and the do seem like a more elegant solution, but  I would need to move the address decoding from the FPGA to an external circuit.

Comment: Did you by any chance check the RC time constant such a resistor would give? || If you know the SNES hardware is TTL / NMOS (I don't recall what it is offhand; it's of the right age I'd expect static CMOS?), you might just run that straight into LVCMOS and not mind the slight overvoltage (3.5-3.6V, still tolerable at 3.3V -- though with no margin). || Why would address decoding have to be external? Think about it ;)

Comment: @TimWilliams After reading what a RC time constant is on Wikipedia (my formal education boils down to using an Arduino kit in class), I can say that I lack the knowledge to know why it is relevant & that I don't know the circuit capacitance would be. || The SNES is internally 5V CMOS, but apparently accepts 5V TTL on its data bus. || Now that you mention it, I could connect the CPU /RD pin directly to the bus interface DIR pin & put the top 3 bits of the address bus into a NAND gate and connect the output to the bus interface /OE pin, or something similar.